# Using division polynomials to prove that EC discrete log is even

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

This question is related to the other [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66410/proving-that-the-least-significant-bit-of-an-elliptic-curve-discrete-logarithm-i) I recently asked. I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to use [division polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials) to prove that knowing $A = a \cdot G$ we can prove that $a$ is even without disclosing the value of $a$.

One useful property of division polynomials that I've observed is that:

$$
\psi_{nk}(G) = \psi_k(G)^{n^2} \cdot \psi_n(k \cdot G)
$$

For even division polynomials this can be re-written as:

$$
\psi_{2k}(G) = \psi_k(G)^4 \cdot \psi_2(k \cdot G)
$$

If we define $a = 2k$ and $A' = A / 2$, and assuming coordinates of $A'$ are $(x_{a'}, y_{a'})$, we can re-write this as:

$$
\psi_{a}(G) = \psi_k(G)^4 \cdot \psi_2(A') = \psi_k(G)^4 \cdot 2y_{a'}
$$

Using this we can prove that $a$ is even by doing the following:

1. Prover computes $s = \psi_{a}(G)$ and $v =\psi_k(G)$ and shares $(s, v)$ with the verifier.
2. The verifier computes $A/2$ and verifies that $s = v^4 \cdot 2y_{a'}$

---

Are there any flaws in this approach?

Comment: How does this prove that $a < \text{Order}(G)$?

Comment: Can't I just pick any random $v$ and compute $s$ to make the verification equation work? How would the verifier check that indeed $s=\psi_a(G)$ and $v=\psi_k(G)$ without knowing $a$ or $k$?

Comment: @poncho - I don't think it does. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @yyyyyyy I thought it would be possible to prove these using relation $x_a = x_g - \frac{\psi_{a-1}(G) \cdot \psi_{a+1}(G)}{\psi_a(G)^2}$ - though, I haven't thought it through completely.

Comment: It would be a problem; after all, given $a$ s.t. $A = a \ G$, we have $a' = a + \text{Order}(G)$ where we also have $A = a' \ G$, and (assuming the order of $G$ is odd), one of $a, a'$ is even and the other odd.  So, if the original $a$ happens to be odd, he could substitute $a'$, and the protocol would claim that "a" is even...

Comment: @poncho - I see. I wonder if it is possible to prove that $a < N$ (where $N = Order(G)$) using the following relation: $\psi_{a+sN}(G) = c^{as} \cdot d^{s^2} \cdot \psi_a(G)$, where $c$ and $d$ are constants defined by the curve parameters.